# Want to convert a string in one form into another form?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like

```
"isnull(col_name,0)<>1 or isnull(col1_name,0)=0 and isnull(col2_name,0)>=100... "
```

I want to convert above string in below form as:

" `(col_name is null or col_name<>1)` or `(col1_name is null or col1_name=0)` and `(col2_name is null or col2_name>=100)`...  "

I want to implement this in JAVA. I have tried with using split function but the case is not the similar everytime(means is between two there may be 'OR' or 'AND', so how to split?).
Then I tried with contains function but how to replace that complete part of isnull in required form. (I have also tried with using character array,it works somewhat fine but fails somewhere according to my code.)

Actually I tried a lot with different ways but I am not able to build the good logic which will work fast.

Pls suggest me some good idea for this. Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the space at the front of the output result necessary? (Do you want it included?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.replaceAll("isnull\\(([^,]+),\\d+\\)([^\\d]+)(\\d+)", "($1 is null or $1$2$3)");`

Comment: Was writing an answer, but realized regex was indeed the way to go. I think that the ,0 means "or" - ,1 probably means "and". How should the regex be changed to allow "and" aswell?

Comment: `str.replaceAll("isnull\\(([^,]+),0\\)([^\\d]+)(\\d+)", "($1 is null or $1$2$3)").replaceAll("isnull\\(([^,]+),1\\)([^\\d]+)(\\d+)", "($1 is null and $1$2$3)")` if that's what you imply.

Comment: Thanks  Alexander Pavlov for quick reply. I have tried this but it is not replacing anything. My original string is as it is after applying this regular expression. I check it by displaying string on console.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the snippet of code of Alexander and the way you used it? Perhaps you're not assigning the string, and just calling the function.

Comment: Sorry Alexander Pavlov. Its working exactly what I want. Previously while fetching that string, square brackets are included in it and hence its not working.
Sorry for my misleading.
Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Copy-pasting can give unexpected results, especially in Eclipse (while pasting into strings between quotes).