# Converting string query from one form to another

Tags: java, string

I have a string that contains conditions using Boolean operators like:

```
 1)   OR(key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3)

 2)   AND(key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3,key4:value4,key5:value5)

 3)   NOT(key1:value1,key2:value2)

 4) AND(key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3,OR(key4:value4,key5:value5),NOT(key6:value6,key7:value7))
```

Now I want to convert this to another format as shown below:

```
1)    key1='value1' OR key2='value2' OR key3='value3'

2)    key1='value1' AND key2='value2' AND key3='value3' AND key4='value4' AND key5='value5'

3)    NOT(key1='value1' OR key2='value2')

4)    ( key1='value1' AND key2='value2' AND key3='value3' ) AND ( key4='value4' OR key5='value5') AND ( NOT(key6='value6' OR key7='value7'))
```

I am going through this link: [Want to convert a string in one form into another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377589/want-to-convert-a-string-in-one-form-into-another-form-in-java)

But I am not clear how to achieve this using regular expressions. Please let me know how to do this in Java

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: @rai.skumar yes, I tried using replace function in String class but I cannot use it to convert my 4th data in my question. Then I came across the post in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377589/want-to-convert-a-string-in-one-form-into-another-form

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.replaceAll()` method.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                         String replacement)

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular 
expression with the given replacement.
```

So, for example, for the first string -

```
"OR(key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3)"
```

You could have

```
String string = "OR(key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3)";

string = string.replaceAll("OR","");
string = string.replaceAll("(","");
string = string.replaceAll(")","'");
string = string.replaceAll(":","='");
string = string.replaceAll(",","' OR ");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeBlue, but how to convert the 4th string which I mentioned in my question. That is the one which I am not able to convert using replace functions.